# how to print a negative cycle in a graph G?

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle, bellman-ford

how can I find a negative cycle in a directed weighted graph. I know how the Bellman Ford algorithm works, and that it tells me if there is a reachable negative cycle. But it does not explicitly name it.

How can I get the actual path v1,v2,…vk,v1 of the cycle?

After applying the standard algorithm we already did n−1 iterations and no further improvement should be possible. If we can still lower the distance to a node, a negative cycle exists.

let say edge (v,u) is the edge that the bellman ford algorithm faild in the n-th iteration - d(u) > d(v) + w(v,u).
so we know that v,u is part of a negative cycle but the question is how do i detect the specific cycle?

Comment: How about running Bellman Ford again with u (or v) as source and for n iterations instead of n-1. At some point u.d<0, stop and print the path from u to u.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this ques ..we use bellman-ford algo . To print the cycle we store the parents of the nodes in a vector(par). Also there can be multiple cycle so when in Nth iteration we find the -ve cycle .So for that we make a visited array and go to the starting of cycle than using the par(parent vector) we can find the path of the cycle.
My code that can help u

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
#define ll long long 
int main(){
    int n,m;
    cin>> n>>m;
    vector<vector<pair<int,ll int > >>graph(n+1);
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
       ll int a,b,c;
       cin>> a>> b>> c;
       graph[a].push_back({b,c});
    }

    vector<ll int >dist(n+1,1e14),par(n+1,-1);

    // applying bellman ford algo.

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
       for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
           for(auto k:graph[j]){
                ll int node=k.first,c=k.second;
                if(dist[node]>c+dist[j]){
                    dist[node]=c+dist[j];
                    par[node]=j;
                }
           }
       }
    }


    // checking nth iteration 


    bool flag=false;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
       for(auto k:graph[i]){
          ll int node=k.first,c=k.second;
          if(dist[node]>c+dist[i]){
             dist[node]=c+dist[i];
             par[node]=i;
             flag=true;
          }
            
          if(flag){

            // negative cycle founded
            
            cout<<"YES cycle founded"<<endl;

            vector<int >ans;
            vector<bool>vis(n+1,false);


            //  loop for finding the start of cycle
            while(!vis[i]){
                vis[i]=true;
                i=par[i];
            }

            
            // pushing the nodes of path in vector(ans).

            int u=i;
            ans.push_back(u);
            u=par[u];
            while(u^i){
                ans.push_back(u);
                u=par[u];
            }
            ans.push_back(u);
            reverse(ans.begin(),ans.end());


            //printing path

            for(auto z:ans)cout<<z<<" ";
            return 0;
            }
       }
    }   

    if(!flag)cout<<"NO cycle founded"<<endl;
}
```

problem link- https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1197/

Comment: what's the value of i in the while loop, the very first time we run it?